# Material Ui datepicker - Styling the calendar icon in the text field

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to style the calendar icon (to be specific increase the font-size of the icon) inside material UI's keyboard datepicker text field in React.

```js
<KeyboardDatePicker
  keyboard={!this.props.isDisabled}
  keyboardIconProps={{ fontSize: "35px" }}
  clearable
  disabled={this.props.isDisabled}
  error={this.state.isError}
  helperText={this.state.errorMsg}
  pickerRef={node => (this.picker = node)}
  InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true, disabled: this.props.isDisabled }}
  onError={console.log}
  value={this.props.storeValue}
  onChange={this.onChangeCallback}
  format={this.props.displayFormat}
  onBlur={this.onBlurCallback}
  disableOpenOnEnter
  InputLabelProps={this.inputLabelProps}
  disableFuture={this.props.disableFuture}
  disablePast={this.props.disablePast}
/>
```

I tried setting the KeyboardButtonProps but it doesn't seem to set the style of the icon. I searched online and there are no solutions for my problem. Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Can you please provide an online example, at least a link to material-ui component that you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you use [KeyBoardDatePicker](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker) from [@material-ui/pickers](https://material-ui-pickers.dev)

You can change the icon via the `keyboardIcon` prop which expects a ReactNode as a child.

Basically just add the following `prop` to your component

```js
keyboardIcon={<SomeReactElement/>}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/customicon-1uj5t) you have a working sandbox

Comment: I did the same solution yesterday and it worked for me. Anyways thanks for taking time to provide answer :)