# How can i replace the navigation icons of react-material-ui datepicker?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Is there any way to replace the navigation icons of react-material-ui datepicker? I have tried a lot but nothing works.

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiPickersCalendarHeader-iconButton" tabindex="0" type="button">
  <span class="MuiIconButton-label">
    <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
      <path d="M15.41 16.59L10.83 12l4.58-4.59L14 6l-6 6 6 6 1.41-1.41z"></path>
      <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0V0z"></path>
    </svg>
  </span>
  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this: [Material Ui datepicker - Styling the calendar icon in the text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60615260/material-ui-datepicker-styling-the-calendar-icon-in-the-text-field)

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/customicon-1uj5t) you have a working sandbox.